# Modify Date without DateAdd or DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to modify the day part of a date without having to use DateAdd or having to calculate the date difference?

```
SET @ReturnDate = '5/16/2012'

SET @ModifyDay = 20
```

Modify only `16` to `20`

Result should be `5/20/2012`

The reason for this is that I am translating vb code into a stored proc:

```
    Dim InvDate_Day_of_Month As Integer = CInt(Day(InvDate))
    PaymentDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, 1, InvDate)
    PaymentDate = New Date(PaymentDate.Year, PaymentDate.Month, DayofTheMonth)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What have you got against `DATEADD`?

Comment: Other databases provide date constructor functions.  In SQL Server, the best way is to use string functions, such as:  cast(replace(@ReturnDate, '/16/', '/20/') as date).

Comment: I have vb code instead, just posted

Comment: But why don't you want to use `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: To avoid complexity. Datepart does the job in a very simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @ReturnDate = @ReturnDate + (@ModifyDay - DATEPART(day, @ReturnDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to add 4 days to the date, you can literally just add 4 to it:

```
DECLARE @ReturnDate DATETIME;
SET @ReturnDate = '5/16/2012'

SELECT @ReturnDate, @ReturnDate + 4
```

This selects 
**2012-05-16** 00:00:00.000 and **2012-05-20** 00:00:00.000